# Full Width Mobile Responsive Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to build a menu in bootstrap, i need it to fit the width of my page container and be mobile responsive as well, i've been trying for a while but can't seem to get it right.  This is what it looks like when i am done:

[image]

As you can see there is this huge wide gap above the links and i don't get why it is there.

This is my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you have the css code? Also, place it in jsfiddle please

Comment: It's bootstrap, no other css code.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup looks fine and no margin on my side when I copy-pasted it. Use the dev tools (F12 in browser) to look at the styles and see if there is something causing that margin-top/padding-top to happen.

Comment: I have done that already, that space on top shows when there are a lot of links.  If i remove some of the links the space disappears but the links display in the middle somewhat.

Comment: Can you supply a plunkr or jsfiddle? I've tried it again and I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @ItamarL. use comment on original post, this does not provide a useful answer to the question

Comment: Didn't have enough rep at the time to comment.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this for some reason was 'pull-right' and 'pull-left' classes i was using for my logo and motto.  I took it out now it displays fine.